# How to change the text in application bar to upper case in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my windows phone application i'm using application bar, but i can not change the font of the letter in the menubutton of my application bar(in all the case it is in lower case only).
How can i change the text to upper case?

Comment: The question is worded differently, but the answer will be the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607712/creating-a-wp7-application-bar-from-scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible directly you can use a third party only!